# Excel: Help me use COUNTIFS to find A or B, but NOT A and B

Tags: excel

I have this questionnaire that has a score for answers in 3 rows (3 questionnaires). I need to find the ones that have either `Q1 >=30` or `Q2 >12` or `Q3 <=33`. I've been googling and trying solutions but failed when compared by counting manually.

See screenshot (rows `AN / AT / BC` would be the answers for Q1 / Q2 / Q3):

[image]

On rows `BD/BE` you can see my manual count, which was a PITA and is prone to error.

This formula helped me count ALL values including `Q1+Q2+Q3`:

```
=COUNTIFS(AN4:AN147;">=30";AT4:AT147;">=12";BC4:BC147;">=0"; BC4:BC147;"<=33")
```

What I need the formula for is to find instances where AN or AT or BC has a given value. For AN it's >=30, for AT it's >=12 and for BC it's <=33. For example, if one responder has 31(!), 10, 40, then he should be counted as "1" (or just counted), if one responder has 31(!), 15(!), 41; then he should also be counted as "1"), if one responder has 25), 10, 41; then he shouldn't be counted.

This is a burnout syndrome scale called Maslach Burnout Inventory, what I'm trying to get here are those at risk of burnout (must have 1 or 2 of those 3 sub-questionnaires altered, but not all 3 as those individuals *have* burnout syndrome)

Here's a sample using markdown generator as requested:

```
| AN    | AT    | BC    |       |       |
|----   |----   |----   |---    |---    |
| 14    | 11    | 41    |       |       |
| 14    | 4     | 43    |       |       |
| 50    | 9     | 41    |       |       |
| 38    | 16    | 20    |       |       |
```

edit: can't get to display it properly, hmm.
edit2: got it

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57121154/edit) to explain exactly what it is you want to achieve? What are `Q1`, `Q2` and `Q3`? What are you counting in this table? etc. It is probably worth it for you to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Wouldn't that be `=COUNTIFS(AN4:AN147;">=30")+COUNTIFS(AT4:AT147;">=12")+COUNTIFS(BC4:BC147;">=0", BC4:BC147,"<=33")`

Comment: You'd have to adjust for double-counting where (say) AN7>=30 and AT7>=12

Comment: You just need to sum the counts for each condition individually.  BTW, your screenshot of data is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. Having to manually enter the data is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Many won't download a workbook, but that's another option.

Comment: I'm assuming that OP wants the number of rows which satisfy at least one condition, not the number of individual questions that satisfy one of the conditions... BD & BE seem to indicate this (sort of)

Comment: To be more exact, BD=1 indicates all three conditions satisfied and BE=1 indicates either one or two.

Comment: @TomSharpe Clearly, clarification of his requirements would be helpful.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry the message was so confusing, I meant it to make it as easy as possible and it seems I did the opposite. I edited the first message and added more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it :

```
=SUMPRODUCT( ( ( (AN4:AN7>=30)+(AT4:AT7>12)+(BC4:BC7<=33) )=1)
+( ( (AN4:AN7>=30)+(AT4:AT7>12)+(BC4:BC7<=33) )=2) )
```

@Ron Rosenfeld's formula is a shorter and more elegant way of accomplishing the same thing.

Anyway if you consider some dummy data like that in the screenshot below which shows rows which satisfy 0,1,2 and 3 of the criteria respectively, my formula works as follows:

Row 4:

```
(FALSE+FALSE+FALSE = 1) => 0+0+0 = 1 => 0=1 => FALSE
(FALSE+FALSE+FALSE = 2) => 0+0+0 = 2 => 0=2 => FALSE
FALSE+FALSE => 0
```

Row 5:

```
(TRUE +FALSE+FALSE = 1) => 1+0+0 = 1 => 1=1 => TRUE
(FALSE+FALSE+FALSE = 2) => 0+0+0 = 2 => 0=2 => FALSE
TRUE+FALSE => 1
```

Row 6:

```
(TRUE +TRUE +FALSE = 1) => 1+1+0 = 1 => 2=1 => FALSE
(TRUE +TRUE +FALSE = 2) => 1+1+0 = 2 => 2=2 => TRUE
FALSE+TRUE => 1
```

Row 7:

```
(TRUE +TRUE +TRUE = 1) => 1+1+1 = 1 => 3=1 => FALSE
(TRUE +TRUE +TRUE = 2) => 1+1+1 = 2 => 3=2 => FALSE
FALSE+FALSE => 0
```

Sumproduct adds up the four totals.

[image]

---

There is another way of doing it (perhaps more for interest than practical use, but doesn't involve pseudo-array formulas):

```
=COUNTIF(AN4:AN7,">=30")+COUNTIF(AT4:AT7,">=12")+COUNTIF(BC4:BC7,"<=33")
-COUNTIFS(AN4:AN7,">=30",AT4:AT7,">=12")-COUNTIFS(AN4:AN7,">=30",BC4:BC7,"<=33")-COUNTIFS(AN4:AN7,">=12",BC4:BC7,"<=33")
```

The first line of the formula just adds up the individual questions that satisfy one of the criteria. But then in the case where two criteria are satisfied, we would have double counting. So we have to subtract one for each of those pairs. What about the case when three criteria are satisfied? We would end up subtracting one three times, which brings us back to zero, so that is OK.

Looking at the Venn diagram might help:

[image]

**Note** there is some evidence [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54666441/using-or-logic-on-an-array-as-argument-in-sumproduct/54722291#54722291) that even multiple sumifs may be faster than sumproducts for this type of problem, but only relevant if you have a *lot* of data.

Comment: fantastic! it worked. I'm still trying to figure out how it worked, since I tried using SUM and I got a wrong answer. I'll be looking forward to the details. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(((AN>=30)+(AT>=12)+((BC>=0)*(BC<=33)))={1,2}))
```

where `AN`, `BC` and `AT` are named ranges that refer to the obvious.

In your original formula, you also tested that `BC>0` so I included it above.

However, if that test is not necessary, the formula can be shortened to:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(((AN>=30)+(AT>=12)+(BC<=33))={1,2}))
```

The Formula Evaluation tool can help you figure out what is going on.
And in the screen shot below, the `byRow` column is not required. It is only there to demonstrate the results of the test on each line, for learning purposes.

- Each equality test returns an array of `{TRUE,FALSE}` depending on the results.

  - In Excel `TRUE=1` and `FALSE=0`.
- Summing the arrays results in an array of `{0,1,2,3}` depending on how many matches there are in each row.
- We then compare those results to see if they are equal to `1` or `2` again returning another `{TRUE, FALSE}` array.
- The `N` function changes the `{TRUE,FALSE}` into `{1,0}` and `SUMPRODUCT` adds the all up.
- One could use the `SUM` function but then you have to remember that, with the array formula, you have to confirm the formula by holding down `ctrl-shift` while hitting `enter` to get the correct result.

[image]